# Storing data in the fragment when activity changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I would like to design a feed-based app with similar design like Facebook, Twitter or Instagram. In the main screen, I have a FeedActivity which holds a ViewPager for holding 3-4 fragments (represented as tabs)

```
FeedActivity

++ ListOfItemsFragment (there is a ListView holding posts)
++ OtherFragment
++ SomeOtherFragment
```

I would like to open another activity (or maybe another fragment in ViewPager) when a user touches a post (listed in ListOfItemsFragment). If I open this new activity (PostDetailActivity) and when I return to the FeedActivity, all data is lost in the ListOfItemsFragment because FeedActivity is created again.

Should I create a new Activity for the post detail, or should I add another fragment to FeedActivity independent of ViewPager (I want this fragment to be a popup, not a part of the tabs).

How can I support this behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want fragment as a dialog?

Comment: I am not sure if it is the best way. I am new to Android development, deciding on which pattern is my problem :)

Comment: very interesting question.  if you dont mind my asking, is your app going to be open source or proprietary?  UPVOTED :)

Comment: The application is not like Facebook, twitter or instagram. I was just trying to explain a tabbed application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you press back the new Activity instance is created. Hense filled data erases. Just type the following lines in manifest file.

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
 </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this resolved my problem. Do I encounter memory errors with this setup? Is this a bad design?

Comment: 1. There should not any memory leaks or errors using this setup.
2. This is the best approach if your views are updated via network call.It saves a lot data. And yep it spares user to enter data everytime user presses back.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the problem from a different perspective, sqlite is a solution.

Plus, there's an added bonus of storing states even if your app is completely destroyed and has to restart.  See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9112082/1166727).

Comment: I am using mysql and php as my backend. I am really confused on how to display activities or fragments.

Comment: that could become a problem in rural areas with insufficient / irregular internet coverage.   you could go long periods of time without achieving connection and thus leave app in background, subject to automatic shutdown by the OS, in extreme cases and/or failure.

Answer (score 0):

Simply override this method and store that data that you want to display again

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("intTag", intValue);   // Save all the value that you want to retain
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}
```

and in you onCreate check if the savedInstanceState is not null than get the value and update your

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    int data = savedInstanceState.getInt("intTag");
    // Retrieve all the data you have settled there
}
```